# How to add persistent aliases on Kali Linux?

Tags: shell, kali-linux, alias

I want to add persistent aliases on my Kali Linux installation and I can't get it to work. All answers I come across is to either add them to `~/.bashrc` or to `~/bash_aliases` (better and recommended), but these don't work for me. Each time I open a new terminal I have to type `source ~/.bash_aliases` to import them.

What I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to dig deeper and after a while I've discovered that in my home directory there are also the following files: `.zshrc` and `.zshrc_history`. After I've searched *kali zshrc* phrase this article pops out:

- https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/linux/kali-linux-20204-switches-the-default-shell-from-bash-to-zsh/

Apparently, since Kali Linux 2020.4 default shell is no longer bash, but zsh, so:

**To add persistent aliases to the Kali Linux on release 2020.4 and newer**, create `~/.shell_aliases` file with your aliases content and reference it in the `~/.zshrc` file as following:

```bsh
if [ -f ~/.shell_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.shell_aliases
fi
```

Of course `.shell_aliases` is just an example, name it as you like as long as it doesn't conflict with anything and is correctly referenced in the `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: You might want to refer to https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/4667

Comment: Well, I did find the answer myself and I don't know why shouldn't I share that with others.

Answer (score -1):

Talking about newer versions of Kali linux

Steps need to be done are:

- creating a new file for aliases

  ```shell
  cd ~
  sudo nano .zsh_aliases
  ```
- adding

  ```shell
  alias update='sudo apt update -y'
  ```
- save it
- need to edit

  ```shell
  sudo nano .zshrc
  ```
- append these at the end of the file

  ```shell
  if [ -f ~/.zsh_aliases ]; then
      . ~/.zsh_aliases
  fi
  ```
- save it
- Source it

  ```shell
  . ~/.zshrc
  ```

Comment: This answer does not appear to add any information past what is already in the accepted answer. The only change is to use `.zsh_aliases` instead of `.shell_aliases`.